# Java - Distance between JLabel and vertical box

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I wrote this code for realize a box into I put four JRadioButtons

```
JRadioButton beginner = new JRadioButton("Beginner"); beginner.setSelected(true);
JRadioButton intermedie = new JRadioButton("Intermedie");
JRadioButton expert = new JRadioButton("Expert");
JRadioButton custom = new JRadioButton("Custom");

Box boxDifficulty = Box.createVerticalBox();
boxDifficulty.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 50));
boxDifficulty.add(beginner);
boxDifficulty.add(intermedie);
boxDifficulty.add(expert);
boxDifficulty.add(custom);
```

Furthermore I set the border of the box using the `setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 50))` method.

Also, I created a JLabel for indicate the title of the box:

```
JLabel difficulty = new JLabel("Choose the difficulty:");
```

This is the portion complete of the code:

```
Box boxDifficulty = Box.createVerticalBox();
boxDifficulty.add(difficulty);
boxDifficulty.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 0, 0, 50));
boxDifficulty.add(beginner);
boxDifficulty.add(intermedie);
boxDifficulty.add(expert);
boxDifficulty.add(custom);
```

How can I increase the space between JLabel and JRadioButton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I increase the space between JLabel and JRadioButton?

You can add a spacing component to the panel after you add the label:

```
boxDifficulty.add(difficulty);
boxDifficulty.add( Box.createVerticalStrut(...) );
```

A strut is a fixed height(width) invisible component.